# How to compound filter search query based on multiple query parameters in haystack?

Tags: django, django-haystack

How do i go about filtering multiple get parameters using a haystack `SearchQuerySet()`?

For example I have the following:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = self.request

    query = request.GET.get('q')
    rarity = request.GET.get('rarity')
    quality = request.GET.get('quality')
    type = request.GET.get('type')
    hero = request.GET.get('hero')

    sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()

    if query is not None:
        sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query)

    return sqs
```

How would I compound filter the sqs result if rarity was not None, or for any combination of parameters that are not equal to None? I could use a bunch of If statements but that doesnt seem to be the best way to go about this.

I tried the following but it doesnt work, is there a better way to do this?

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = self.request

    query = request.GET.get('q')
    rarity = request.GET.get('rarity')
    quality = request.GET.get('quality')
    type = request.GET.get('type')
    hero = request.GET.get('hero')

    sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()

    if query is not None:
        sqs.filter(content=query)
    if rarity is not None:
        sqs.filter(rarity=rarity)

    return sqs
```

I'm not sure if this is the right terminology but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you're trying build a SearchQuerySet using the various keyword args you should assign the *filter* statements back to *sqs* -- that will have the effect of chaining them together: sqs = sqs.filter(content=query) ... then sqs = sqs.filter(rarity=rarity), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `filter` method doesn't modify sqs. It just returns a new SearchQuerySet including the filter. Said that, the expression `sqs.filter(content=query)` won't do nothing if you don't assign it to a variable.

I guess you're trying to do this:

```
    ...
    if query is not None:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content=query)
    if rarity is not None:
        sqs = sqs.filter(rarity=rarity)
    ...
```

Or maybe this:

```
    ...
    if query is not None:
        sqs = sqs.filter_or(content=query)
    if rarity is not None:
        sqs = sqs.filter_or(rarity=rarity)
    ...
```

(By default, filter behaves as filter_and, but that can be changed)